# How to show the data from database in a alert box as html table when td is double clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to show the data from database in a HTML Table and I want to show this html table inside the alert box when the `td` is double clicked, now its showing the data in side the alert box when the `td` is double clicked, but not displaying like html table (note: now it displaying data s in alert box but not as html format), below is my code.

**Ajax**

```js
$('td').dblclick(function() {                

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "supplierprice/retrieve.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
          alert(response);
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
echo '  <td id="alertShow" width="114px;" class="edit region '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>
        <td id="alertShow" width="115px;" class="edit country '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td id="alertShow" width="286px;" class="edit networkname '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td id="alertShow" width="92px;"  class="edit mcc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>  
        <td id="alertShow" width="94px;"  class="edit mnc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
        <td id="alertShow" width="92px;" class="edit mnp '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>';
```

**retrieve.php**:

```php
include"config.php";
$result=mysql_query("select * from supplierpricehistory");

echo "<table border='1' >
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>supplier</b></td>
<td align=center><b>country</b></td>
<td align=center><b>networkname</b></td>
<td align=center><b>mcc</b></td></td>
<td align=center><b>mnc</b></td>
<td align=center><b>newprice</b></td>       
<td align=center><b>oldprice</b></td>       
<td align=center><b>status</b></td>     
<td align=center><b>date</b></td>           
<td align=center><b>user</b></td>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[4]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[5]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[6]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[7]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[8]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[9]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[10]</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Can anyone guide me how to do this or there is any other way to do it. Thanks

Comment: You can't show HTML with standard `alert()`, you need to create your own custom alert box for this.

Comment: You could use a standard `showModalDialog()` or jqueryui, like AnDR0iD3 has proposed, or search for some other from the web.

Comment: can you see http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/4/ where i went wrong

Comment: It's not about what went wrong, but more like a problem with the choice of delivery. Alert can only do plain text, and _NOT_ HTML. You've got to rely on a dialogue/modal box for that purpose.

Comment: @arokia `alert` should not use as an `id`, also there are multiple `id`s like `alertShow` in the fiddle, though with jQuery it somehow works. You're on the track to develope your own dialog/alert box from the snippet at that fiddle. You can find examples also at SO, just do some search...

Answer (score 0):

The standard js alert cannot be formatted. You should use custom dialogs for example http://jqueryui.com/dialog/